# Is there a database of disgusting images for stimuli for experimental study of disgust?

Tags: methodology, data

I'm looking for a set of images that evoke a disgust reaction. In particular, I'm looking for disgusting *objects* (e.g. feces, maggots). Is there a database of images like this? It would be especially useful if there were norming or rating data on how disgusting people found the images.

Comment: Make sure you explain to your subjects what they are going to see and get their written consent. You don't want to get sued for shocking people with images they cannot handle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the IAPS--International Affective Picture System; they have disgusting images as well as norming procedures and data.  You can read about it [here](http://www2.unifesp.br/dpsicobio/Nova_versao_pagina_psicobio/adap/instructions.pdf) and request it (as long as you have a faculty advisor) [here](http://csea.phhp.ufl.edu/media.html#topmedia).

Comment: Is there a way to view samples from IAPS without getting the full set?

Comment: There are some (though not many) if you do a google image search; they try to restrict the use of the images outside of actual research to avoid habituation.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm asking because I'm looking specifically for disgusting objects (I revised my question to reflect this) and I'm not sure if IAPS has the kind of stimuli that I would need.

Comment: It does (it also has a category for objects vs people, if I remember).  Find a faculty advisor and hie then hence.

Answer (score 2):

You may also have a look at the [EmoMadrid](http://www.uam.es/gruposinv/ceaco/EmoMadrid.htm)-database, which can also be accessed for free and the author's do not mention any restrictions of whom they give it to. [Here](http://www.uam.es/gruposinv/ceaco/sup/permisoYclave.htm) are the instructions on how to get access.

Answer (score 2):

There is one for [Trypophobia Image Detector - Browser Plugin using Deep Learning](https://github.com/cytadela8/trypophobia) (repo: https://github.com/cytadela8/trypophobia).

> **[Download the data set v2](https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/trypophobia/tryponet_set2.tar.gz)** prepared in 2017-09
>
> *Note: The provided images may be or not be subjected to copyright. By downloading the data set you agree to use it only for research purposes.*
>
> - **6.5k** trypophobia triggering images obtained from:
>
>   - **6k** Reddit (/r/trypophobia) - using [Prawtimestamps by voussoir](https://github.com/voussoir/reddit.git), wget and [Ripme by 4pr0n](https://github.com/4pr0n/ripme)
>   - **546** Google images (keyword: trypophobia) - using own scrapper
> - **10.5k** neutral images obtained from Google images using own scrapper:
>
>   - **10k** by supplying it 5k randomly chosen words from [this](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words) english dictionary and downloading 2 images per word
>   - **192** with *bushes* keyword (introduced in v2 to eliminate false positives for greenery)
>   - **181** with *grass* keyword (since v2)
>   - **98** with *forest* keyword (since v2)

Full disclosure: it was prepared by two of my mentees. I also used it in [Detecting trypophobia triggers](https://brainhackwarsaw.github.io/#trypophobia) project at the Aspects of Neuroscience hackathon.

In general, you may want to look up [trypophobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trypophobia) Wikipedia entry before using any image search.